# Peak detection(to find distance between two peaks) from the chart plotted in c# from a CSV data file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, charts

I am using c# visual studio 2019 to plot the line chart from CSV file and i am getting several peaks. I want to detect those peaks and know the distance between them. Below is the code that i am using for chart plotting. I would like to add a incremental function in the code to detect the highest peaks and get the distance between them.

Thank you for your attention

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Drawing;


namespace GraphDemo
{
    class Plot
    {
        public Plot(Read rr, ComboBox xBox, ComboBox yBox, Chart chart)
        {
            int indX = xBox.SelectedIndex;
            int indY = yBox.SelectedIndex;
            float[,] data = rr.get_Data();
            int nLines = rr.get_nLines();

            chart.Series.Clear(); //ensure that the chart is empty
            chart.Series.Add("Series0");
            chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

            chart.Legends.Clear();
            for (int j = 0; j < nLines; j++)
            {
                chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(data[j, indX], data[j, indY]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the essence of the problems is "How do you define a 'peak'?"

Emanuele suggests it's any point that is higher than the points either side of it, but in a typical jagged stock-market chart, that could be almost every other point. Most mountains have little rocks every few feet (or inches) that are higher than their surroundings, but wouldn't be considered a peak.

You could apply a smoothing function, recalculating each point as the average of a few points on either side - and then look for the peaks. The problem then is how much smoothing you need.

Or you could decide that a peak only counts if there's a low between them. Again, you need to decide what that value is; is it 10% less, or below the average or something else?

One approach would be to try either of the above methods, and then count the peaks. If there are lots of peaks, you apply more smoothing or filtering until the biggest ones stand out.

Basically, peak detection is the kind of fuzzy pattern matching that humans do without thinking, but it's really hard to describe what we actually mean.